# calculate the number of uppercase and lowercase

Tags: python

Write a Python function that accepts a string and calculates the number of upper case letters and lower case letters.

What's wrong in this code

```
def up_low(sentence):
    uppcas=0
    lowcas=0
    for letter in sentence:
        while letter.isupper():
            uppcas+=1
            pass
        while letter.islower():
            lowcas+=1
            pass
    print ("original String: ", sentence)
    print ("no of uppercase: ", uppcas)
    print ("no of lowercase: ", lowcas)
```

Answer (score 2):

You used `while` instead if `if` in your for-loop, those are infinite loops. (The letter you are currently checking will not change inside the while-body, so it will just re-check if the letter that was lowercase before is still lowercase forever)

What you wanted to do is

```
def up_low(sentence):
    uppcas=0
    lowcas=0
    for letter in sentence:
        if letter.isupper():
            uppcas+=1
        elif letter.islower():  # use elif so this is only checked if isupper() fails
            lowcas+=1
    print ("original String: ", sentence)
    print ("no of uppercase: ", uppcas)
    print ("no of lowercase: ", lowcas)
```

I removed the `pass` which you would use if you want to do nothing. If you need 
the `while`s, you maybe confused `pass` with `break` - that would leave the current loop environment, but if you only go trough an iteration once, you generally want to use `if`.

Comment: You better change the second `if` to `elif` or add `continue` inside the first `if` - uppercase letter shouldn't be checked again.

Comment: @Gabip i'd agree on the `elif`, but adding `continue` here does not improve behaviour and just introduces confusion about what it does and why it would be needed.

Comment: `continue` will function the same, it will return the control to the beginning of the for loop and the second check, `if letter.islower()`, will be skipped.

Comment: I apologize, i misread your 'or' as an 'and'.